# clang_complete in Vim

Tags: vim, clang, clang-complete

So after playing around with omnicpp, gccsense and clang_complete I couldn't get any of them to work. So I `apt-get purge vim-*` and tried again to install clang_complete, but without success.

Here's what I do:

1. Download `clang_complete.vmb`, move it to my fresh, clean `.vim` dir and execute `vim clang_complete.vmb -c 'so %' -c 'q'`.
2. Paste this into my .vimrc:

   ```
   syntax on
   set number
   filetype plugin on
   let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
   let g:clang_complete_auto = 1
   let g:clang_complete_copen = 1
   ```
3. Create a typical example

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>

   int main() { std:: (I get: User defined pattern not found) }
   ```

Is there anything else I need to do/install to get it working? And silly question I've heard about Clang, do I need to `apt-get install` it?

Comment: 1. What kind of completion do you use in vim (keys you press)? 2. Try setting `g:clang_debug = 1` and see if you get any debug messages when you try to complete something, it should print some information every time the plugin is used for autocompletion.

Comment: Also see this how to set up clang_complete + supertab: http://zwiener.org/vimautocomplete.html

Comment: Thanks for tips, I've managed to get it working, for future seekers, it was like I need clang installed for it to work...

Answer (score 25):

**clang_complete** can be configured to use the **clang executable** or the **clang library**

clang_complete uses the clang executable by default but the clang **library will execute lot faster**

### clang_complete plugin (using the clang executable) needs:

1. **clang** must be installed in your system and be in the PATH
2. **do not** set (let) g:clang_library_path to a path containing the libclang.so library

### clang_complete plugin (using the clang library) needs:

1. **python** installed in your system
2. vim must be built with python support (do **:version** and look for a **+python/dyn** or  **+python3/dyn** entry)
3. set (let) **g:clang_library_path** to the directory path where **libclang.so** is contained

Comment: where is `libclang.so` located? for example on ubuntu

Comment: ah, found it `/usr/lib/libclang.so`

Comment: clang_complete plugin doesn't seem to work... `clang` is in my `PATH` and I'm not setting the clang_library_path, but I get "Loading libclang failed, completion won't be available. Consider setting g:clang
_library_path." when using Ubuntu's libclang (version 3.5). My Ubuntu version is 14.10.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between the executable and the library option. May be this is the reason,I was not able to fix this issue in past and jumped to YCM. But this time I tried this and clang_complete is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`let g:clang_library_path='/usr/lib/llvm3.5/lib/libclang.so.1'`  in my .vimrc
and it works fine.