# clang_complete pattern not found for C structs

Tags: c, vim, clang, clang-complete

So I have a very basic C program to try and test `clang_complete`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct xampl {
  int x;
};

int main()
{
  struct xampl structure;
  struct xampl *ptr1;
}
```

However, every time I try to do structure. or `ptr1->`, the program gives me the error:

> User defined completion (`^U^N^P`) Pattern not found.

I tried adding this to my `vimrc`:

```
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0' --
```

(from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901129/clang-complete-doesnt-work)) but, the completion still doesn't work.

Is there something I am missing or not understanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `ptr->` you mean `ptr1->` right?
I have only two strings in my .vimrc

```
let g:clang_complete_copen=1
let g:clang_hl_errors=1
```

and your example works fine for me. Make sure you have **.clang_complete** file with valid include paths (see `:help clang_complete` for example file). Try to debug clang completer by set up variable `let g:clang_debug=1`. And read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259485/clang-complete-in-vim) maybe it help you.

Comment: Sorry I did mean, ptr1.  I don't have a .clang_complete file in my vim directory, and the FAQ is very vague on how to fix the pattern not found issue.  Where should I put/create the .clang_complete file? Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem.  Didn't know you had install clang for it to work.  Thanks for the thread link!