# vim clang_complete "-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found"

Tags: vim, clang-complete

I'm new to vim and I'm trying to get code completion to work. I'm using clang_complete and vim-cmake-project. I open my project by typing `:CMake projectdirectory` It opens my project and I can select which file I want to open but when I try to trigger clang_complete it says, `-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found.` I added this to my `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:clang_complete_auto = 1
let g:clang_use_library = 1
let g:clang_debug = 1
let g:clang_library_path = '/usr/lib/'
let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'
```

However, I still get the same error. Also I have clang and libclang-dev packages installed. So what else can I do to get clang_complete to work?

Comment: Related question: [clang_complete in VIM](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10259485).

Comment: Yeah, actually added the path because I read that thread. I have everything they said I would need except I have +python and +python3 but they don't have /dyn. I don't know if that changes anything? What does the /dyn mean and how do I get it?

Comment: Do you have clang and llvm installed properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [clang complete doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901129/clang-complete-doesnt-work)

Comment: @timss Where do you think I got "let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'" from? That thread! It does not help.

Comment: I can create a helloworld project and code completion works fine. This error only happens when I try to open my large project.

Comment: @SteveButcher No need to be upset about it.. Also, are you sure your code is correct? I can't remember correctly, but I believe you might encounter such an error if there's a problem in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing ctrl+X will force it to complete which appears to work fine. Still not sure why it happens. I suspect you have to create a .clang_complete file but I never could get the python script to work.

Answer (score 0):

My configure as follow:
1) .vimrc add:
   let g:clang_user_options='|| exit 0'

2) add .clang_complete code browser directory
   eg.
   -I../mylib/include

When appear "-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found",
I find that i miss add some include dirs to .clang_complete.